# a simple proverb : 가는 말이 고와야 오는 말이 곱다

Tags: grammar, meaning

Newbie here.
I try to decypher a simple proverb, 가는 말이 고와야 오는 말이 곱다. [The global meaning is clear](https://www.reddit.com/r/Korean/comments/ajnmpl/%EC%86%8D%EB%8B%B4korean_proverbs_of_the_day_%EA%B0%80%EB%8A%94_%EB%A7%90%EC%9D%B4_%EA%B3%A0%EC%99%80%EC%95%BC_%EC%98%A4%EB%8A%94_%EB%A7%90%EC%9D%B4_%EA%B3%B1%EB%8B%A4/) but I don't understand some details.

Vocabulary's ok to me (see *infra*) but I have three questions about (1) spelling (2) grammar and (3) meaning.

(1) Is 고와야 pronouced goaya or gowaya ?

(2) What's exactly 고와야 ? Is it [곱다 + suffix 아/어 + 야](http://www.koreanwikiproject.com/wiki/%EC%95%84/%EC%96%B4_%2B_%EC%95%BC_%EB%90%98%EB%8B%A4) ?
**But what's the meaning of this suffix here ?**

(3) Litterary, this is what I understand:

**If(?)** the words [that] go [to you] are right, the words [that] come [to you] are right [too].

Any help would be appreciated !

---

Vocabulary:

- 이 [i] : subject marker
- 가다  [gada]  : to go
- 말   [mal]   : word(s), speech(es)
- 오다  [oda]   : to come
- 곱다  [gopda] : ~to be beautifull, to be pure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (1) Is 고와야 pronouced goaya or gowaya ?

gowaya

> (2) What's exactly 고와야 ? Is it 곱다 + suffix 아/어 + 야 ? But what's the meaning of this suffix here ?

Yes, you are right. Above suffix has a meaning of a kind of  obligation.

`[A] suffix 아/어야 [B]` means `must [A] to [B]`

> (3) Literary, this is what I understand:
>
> If(?) the words [that] go [to you] are right, the words [that] come [to you] are right [too].

Of course above proverb has above meaning. But the nuance is stronger. And `곱다` means `nice` rather than `right`

`The going words must be nice, then coming word is nice.`